# Unable to locate package docker-sync

Tags: 16.04, apt, docker

MY OS is

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

I want to install docker-sync in my os, but I am receiving below error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-sync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-sync
```

Anybody knows, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-sync` is not in any of Xenial's official repositories (16.04).

You can install it using:

```
gem install docker-sync
```

- To be able to use `gem` you should have `ruby` installed.

For more specific instruction have a look at [here](https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/wiki/docker-sync-on-Linux).